# Software package fails installing because of permissions

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions, java, users

I'm busy installing WS02 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server edition, right now I am facing some problems regarding permissions I guess below is my terminal log. I checked the directory with $JAVA_HOME and JAVA -Version what else can I verify or troubleshoot? I also checked whoami with sudo and without.

```
ws02@ws02:~$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/: Is een map
ws02@ws02:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
ws02@ws02:~$ cd /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/bin
ws02@ws02:/usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/bin$ sh wso2server.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1
rm: kan '/usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/tmp/work' niet verwijderen: Toegang geweigerd
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log (Toegang geweigerd)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [CARBON_LOGFILE].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/repository/logs/patches.log (Toegang geweigerd)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/repository/logs/wso2carbon-trace-messages.log (Toegang geweigerd)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE].
[2016-05-06 11:50:30,113]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.Main} -  Cannot write wso2carbon.pid file
[2016-05-06 11:50:30,121] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.FragmentBundleCreator} -  Error occured while creating the log4j prop fragment bundle.
java.io.IOException: Fail to create the directory: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/tmp/jarsToBundles
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.util.Utils.copyFileToDir(Utils.java:492)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.FragmentBundleCreator.perform(FragmentBundleCreator.java:70)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
[2016-05-06 11:50:30,132] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Failed to create the directory: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/tmp/bundles_info_e05b517c-df68-4d71-9158-99d271db6dea/bundles.info
java.io.IOException: Failed to create the directory: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/tmp/bundles_info_e05b517c-df68-4d71-9158-99d271db6dea/bundles.info
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.updateBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:312)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.perform(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:78)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
[2016-05-06 11:50:30,132] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer} -  Error occured while deploying bundles in the dropins directory
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while updating the bundles.info file.
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.updateBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:334)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.perform(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:78)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create the directory: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/tmp/bundles_info_e05b517c-df68-4d71-9158-99d271db6dea/bundles.info
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.updateBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:312)
    ... 9 more
[2016-05-06 11:50:30,136] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.PatchInstaller} -  Error occurred while applying patches
java.io.IOException: Bestand of map bestaat niet
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils.processPatches(PatchUtils.java:204)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.PatchInstaller.perform(PatchInstaller.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
[2016-05-06 11:50:30,136] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.EclipseIniRewriter} -  Error while writing to file null.ini
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/repository/components/default/null.ini (Toegang geweigerd)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.EclipseIniRewriter.rewriteFile(EclipseIniRewriter.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.EclipseIniRewriter.perform(EclipseIniRewriter.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:152)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.EclipseIniRewriter.rewriteFile(EclipseIniRewriter.java:84)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.EclipseIniRewriter.perform(EclipseIniRewriter.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:152)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
    ... 6 more
ws02@ws02:/usr/bin/wso2/wso2emm-2.0.1/bin$ sudo sh wso2server.sh
[sudo] wachtwoord voor ws02:
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
 CARBON cannot execute java
```

Hope to get some help so I can proceed the installation,
Is it a permission problem ? PATH problem? User right problem?
Only thing I have done is installed Ubuntu GUI on the server because of this problem.

Cheers

PS below is more info about the software I want to install and the prerequisite about it.

```
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/Installing+on+Linux+or+OS+X
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/Prerequisites
```

Comment: Try `sudo -E` - it copies over environment variables

Comment: It working I keep you up to date

Answer (score 0):

you should not need to explicitly start sh (when the script includes a [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))), Which will not reuse the currently set environment variables. So try

```
./wso2server.sh
```

or

```
sudo ./wso2server.sh
```

Comment: It wont work same permission denied error

Comment: From your question it seems that the problem is not permissions, but that the environment is not setup correctly:  `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.`. so you should set the `JAVA_HOME` env-var for all users (or use `sudo -E` as workaround)